# Run-Time Check Failure #2 Stack around the variable 'A' was corrupted

Tags: c++

I've been getting this error for the code I'll post below. On going thru debugging and using breaks, it's breaking the program after the end of the program (ie. after the last } in main). I thought it was an overflow issue, but I am not seeing where there might be an array overflow. I've tried changing the numbers or fiddling around with the for loop when reading it in, but I'm not sure what would cause it to be breaking after the end of the program if it isn't an overflow problem. The program is supposed to run binary and sequential search on an array of 500 random integers

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

//Global variables for 3-way comparison count

int binarycomparisoncount = 0; 
int sequentialcomparisoncount = 0;

//Implements binary search on the sorted array

int BinarySearch(int A[], int n, int Key)
{
    int l = 0;
    n = n - 1;
    int m = 0;

    while (l < n)
    {
        m = (l + n) / 2;
        
        if (Key = A[m])
            return m;
        else if (Key < A[m])
            n = m - 1;
        else
            l = m + 1;

        binarycomparisoncount++;
    }

    return -1;
}

//Implements sequential search on the sorted array

int SequentialSearch(int A[], int n, int Key)
{
    int i = 0;

    A[n] = Key;

    while (A[i] != Key)
    {
        i = i + 1;
        sequentialcomparisoncount++;
    }

    if (i < n)
        return i;
    else 
        return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    ifstream infile; //infile variable
    int A[500] = { NULL }; //Array of size 500
    int Key; //The search key for the variable to be searched for in both search functions
    int i = 0; //Counter for reading in array
    int arraysize = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]); //Arraysize for sort function

    infile.open("input.txt");

    //Reads in from file to array

    for(int j=0; j<arraysize; j++)
    {
        infile >> A[i];
        i++;
    }

    sort(A, A+arraysize); //Uses C++ library function to sort the array

    cout << "Please enter the number to search for: ";
    cin >> Key;

    BinarySearch(A, 500, Key);
    SequentialSearch(A, 500, Key);

    cout << "The number of comparisons for Binary Search was: " << binarycomparisoncount << endl;
    cout << "The number of comparisons for Sequential Search was: " << sequentialcomparisoncount << endl;

    infile.close();

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `SequentialSearch`, on this line:

```
A[n] = Key;
```

you are invoking undefined behavior by accessing `A` out of bounds. In this case, `A` has only 500 elements, but `n` is 500. For an array of 500 elements, the only valid indexes are 0 to 499.

Comment: Yup, that was it, didn't even notice that when going over it. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)